# Unable to connect to Docker SQL Server container from other container in an ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, docker-compose

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  trackingdb:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: YourStrong@Passw0rd
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
    ports:
      - "5532:1433"
    networks:
      - mynetwork
  trackapi:
    image: trackapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Track.API/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5001:80"
      - "5011:443"
    depends_on:
      - trackingdb
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
```

In the container trackapi I use:

```
"ConnectionString": "Server=trackingdb,5532;Database=TrackingChain;User Id=sa;Password=YourStrong@Passw0rd;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
```

I get this error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

If I try to connect with SQL Server Management Studio from my computer with `host: localhost,5532`, it works.

If I try to change the connection string from `trackingdb,5532` to `localhost,5532`, it does NOT work.

Comment: Not expert in docker, I think  the DB container expose the port 1433. Try to modify the connection string to `Server=trackingdb,1433;`.

Comment: In the compose file `ports: "5532:1433"` is taking the SQL Server container's `expose` port (1433) and `publish`ing it on the Docker host (5532). Have you tried either `Server=trackingdb,1433;` or `Server=host.docker.internal,5532;` yet?

Comment: Aside... the `SA_PASSWORD` environment variable has been deprecated for some time already. As per the [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) you probably want to transition to using the `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` environment variable instead.

Comment: trackingdb,1433   work!!!  So insied of my container i need to use internal port, thanks!